# Displaying data from 2 tables and ordering them

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have got 2 tables with the same fields:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class Post2(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

I am displaying them on the same page:

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all(),
        'post2': Post2.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

I use that in the html:

```
  {% for post in posts %}
    <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
  {% for post in post2 %}
    <p>{{ post2.title }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
```

What I am trying to do is display them all based on the date posted. Currently its doing so, but the tables are not mixed. First are displayed the posts from table `Post` ordered by date, and then there are displayed posts from table `Post2` based on date. Is there a way to order by date, but taking to consideration both tables, so the posts from both tables would be mixed and displaying in order by date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `union`

```
def home(request):

    posts = Post.objects.all()
    posts2 = Post2.objects.all()

    posts_together = posts.union(posts2, all=True).order_by() 
    #all=True to allow duplicates
    
    # you can use order_by() with date 
    
    context = {
        'posts_together': posts_together
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Here is [doc about union](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#union)